# ¿Cómo crear un objeto iterable desde un objeto de WikipediaPage?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de cambiar un rango de documentos de un proyecto que necesita un modelo que requiere una gran cantidad de memoria RAM para ser entrenada a una más simple basada en la biblioteca `wikipedia`.

Tengo `queries`, una lista de consultas que contiene solo una consulta en este momento

```
queries : ['What is the population of Toulon']
```

y me gustaría cambiar la forma en que se clasificó al documento más cercano utilizando la función `wikipedia.page ()`. Sin embargo, para el buen funcionamiento de este rango sé que necesito un objeto útil al final. De hecho lo intenté

```
    # Rank documents for queries.
    if len(queries) == 1:
        # ranked = [self.ranker.closest_docs(queries[0], k=n_docs)]
        ranked = [wikipedia.page(queries),wikipedia.page(queries)] # which is stupid I know, but don't know how to do it differently yet.
    all_docids, all_doc_scores = zip(*ranked)
```

y obtuve un error `all_docids, all_doc_scores = zip(*ranked) TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration`.

Por lo momento tengo `<WikipediaPage 'Toulon'> <WikipediaPage 'Toulon'>`

Hay zip porque parece necesario despues :

```
    # Acoplar identificaciones de documentos y recuperar texto de la base de datos. 
    # Eliminar duplicados para la eficiencia del procesamiento.
    flat_docids = list({d for docids in all_docids for d in docids})
    did2didx = {did: didx for didx, did in enumerate(flat_docids)}

    flat_docids = list({d for docids in all_docids for d in docids})
    doc_texts = self.processes.map(fetch_text)
```

Parece que el texto esta solamente  recuperado más tarde que lo hice, en `self.processes.map (fetch_text)` ¿cometí un error?

El archivo completo esta [aqui](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA/blob/master/drqa/pipeline/drqa.py).

Comment: ¿por que usas zip, cual seria el objetivo de ello? ¿que esperas?

Comment: @eyllanesc No soy yo, está lo que Facebook research laboratorio hice en [este archivo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA/blob/master/drqa/pipeline/drqa.py), lo actualicé pero creo que es para Acoplar identificaciones de documentos y recuperar texto de la base de datos. Si puedo deshacerme de él, lo haría con gusto porque su código es realmente complicado...

Comment: Creo que entenderas lo que es un **XY problem**, pienso que es lo usted tiene, en vez de centrarse en el problema original, se esta centrando en solucionar su posible solucion que nadie garantice que funcione, lee el siguiente para que me entiendas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy, despues de hacer eso corrija su pregunta